# Understanding Func<T, TResult> Delegate with MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, delegates

I am trying to wrap my head around **Func < T, TResult>** Delegate but seems like i am not clear. I know that T is a parameter & TResult is a return type.

in MVC I use this Function all the time:

```
@model Products
@Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.my_property)
```

now how does TextBoxFor Function knows that the parameter passed to me is actually a "**Products** Model".

And below is the Signature for TextBoxFor Model:

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
    IDictionary<string, Object> htmlAttributes
)
```

So my question is, when I call Html.TextBoxFor(s), then how come this Method knows "s" is a "Products" Model and how does TModel Maps to parameter "s" (knowing that its Product Model and I need to return something)?

Comment: More probably you use `public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,  Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)` with two parameters.

Comment: The generic type `TModel` gets resolved because you probably have a `@model YourNamespace.Products` statement at the beginning of your view. That statement essentially tells the compiler to call `TextBoxFor` method using your model type. As for your second question, you might want to consider looking up a slightly simpler example of `Action` and `Func` (or in general, [C# delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx)).

Comment: how does HtmlTextBoxFor's TModel knows that the parameter passed to me is "Products" model?

Comment: Because you tell it it will be with the line @model Products

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Html` property (`@Html`) is of type `HtmlHelper<Products>`, because of the `@model Products` directive. This is how the Razor engine works.

`TextBoxFor` is an extension method to `HtmlHelper<TModel>`, and in your code, you're calling it on an instance of `HtmlHelper<Products>`, therefore `TModel` is resolved to `Products`.

Then, the compiler can easily bind `TProperty` to the type of `my_property` from there, as it knows what `TModel` is and can deduce what the lambda *"returns"*.

---

Side note: You must know that `Expression<Func<T>>` is *totally* different from `Func<T>`:

- `Func<...>` is just a simple delegate, a reference to a piece of executable code somewhere, which is *opaque*.
- `Expression<Func<...>>`, on the other hand, is an *expression tree*, which is a kind of [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).

When you write a lambda, the compiler generates different code depending on whether you're assigning the lambda to a `Func<...>` or an `Expression<Func<...>>`. In the first case, it will compile the lambda and generate a delegate. In the second case, it will emit an expression tree.

For an in-depth explanation, you can read Eric Lippert's series *Lambda Expressions vs. Anonymous Methods*: [Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/01/10/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-one.aspx), [Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/01/11/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-two.aspx), [Part 3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/01/12/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-three.aspx), [Part 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/03/26/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-four.aspx), [Part 5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/03/28/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-five.aspx)

Comment: so basiclly its HtmlHelper<Products>.TextBoxFor(s=>s.my_property) where "s" is a provided model.

Comment: @highwingers well... more exactly it's: `InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(Html, s=>s.my_property)`, where `Html.GetType() == typeof(HtmlHelper<Products>)`. The type of the second parameter is bound to `Expression<Func<Products, WhateverTypeMyPropertyIs>>`